# Lenovo X1 yoga brightness changing itself

Tags: gnome, lenovo, syslinux

when i set a brightness level computer changes it to lower level then back to the level set constantly making the screen change its brightness up and down. What can i do.

Comment: Welcome to ask Ubuntu!  Please update your question with the version/kernel of Ubuntu you are running.

Comment: It depends on your Ubuntu version, but this might be that automatic brightness is activated. Go into power settings, under power saving options see if there’s an automatic brightness option that you can switch off.